# How to store an instance object in shelve?

Tags: python, pickle, shelve, dbm

```
instance1 = class_A()
shelve["key1"] = instance1
```

So `instance1` is a reference to an instance of `class_A` stored in memory.

Does the above code dereferences the reference `instance1` and stores the underlying object instance in shelve? Or does it only store the reference?

Because I don't want to store just the reference `instance1` and when the program closes, the underlying object gets released, then the `instance1` reference becomes invalid on next program start.

Comment: Shelves are like persistent dictionaries and the values in this case would be instances of `class_A`. When the program restarts and reopens the shelf later, the keys and associated values (the instances of  `class_A`) will all still be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shelves don't store references to in-memory instances. They serialize objects with `pickle` and store serialized representations, from which objects can later be recreated. It would be impossible for `shelve` to do its job if it tried to store references (and trying to store "the underlying object instance" runs into similar problems).